# How can I compare different rows of different columns in the same table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How can I compare different rows of different columns in the same table in MySQL?? I want to get all the data between given Start_Date and End_Date in my database table. But two dates are not in the same row.Ex,

```
Start_Date    End_Date      Data
2011-07-01    2011-07-31     AA
2011-08-01    2011-08-31     BB
```

I want to get data between `'2011-07-01'` and `'2011-08-31'`.How can I do that? Please reply me with MySQL code.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
where 
Start_Date between  '2011-07-01' and '2011-08-31' 
OR
End_Date between  '2011-07-01' and '2011-08-31'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are You Want the data between '2011-07-01' and '2011-08-31'. Thats Start_Date is 2011-07-01 or more and End_Date is '2011-08-31' or less.

Am I Correct?. If i correct Try below Query.

```
SELECT Data FROM table_Name WHERE Start_Date <= '2011-07-01' AND End_Date >= '2011-08-31'
```

Happy Coding.